# How to prevent additional function loads in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I have some code which I'm using for an instant search:

```
$(function() {
var timer;
$("#searchterm").on('keypress',function() {
    timer && clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(doStuff, 800);
    timer = setTimeout(more, 3600);
});
});
```

Basically, what happens is that the code detects when the user stops typing and fires the `doStuff` function, which loads all the ajax that displays the results. The `more` function is supposed to detect when a user scrolls to the end of the results, and load the next batch with an ajax function, but if a user types in a request then pauses and types in more just as the page loads, it seems to causes the `more` function to fire more than once, which, when a user scrolls to the end of the results, causes the next results to load twice, or sometimes more, which makes the page freeze and generate a ridiculously long list of results. I tried 
to lengthen the delay before the `more` function loads, but this didn't totally solve the problem.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you need to create more variables for the timers? Now it seems you are assigning the timer for `more` to the same variable as the timer for `doStuff`, so it overwrites the timer for `doStuff`.

Maybe something like:

```
$(function() {
    var doStuffTimer, moreTimer;

    $("#searchterm").on('keypress',function() {
        doStuffTimer && clearTimeout(doStuffTimer);
        doStuffTimer = setTimeout(doStuff, 800);

        moreTimer && clearTimeout(moreTimer);
        moreTimer = setTimeout(more, 3600);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is being caused by the fact that you aren't properly clearing the `timer`. I would do something like this:

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/dz9Tv/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input id="stop">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var timer;

$("#stop").keyup(function(){
    $("div").css("background-color", "white");
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(more, 2500);
}).keyup();

var more = function(){
    $("div").css("background-color", "red");
}
```

This clears the `timer` timer that was initially set. If you want to adapt this to your page, what you can do is have the `timer = setTimeout(#dosomething, timeHere)` be called when you scroll to the bottom of the page. Then, you'll need an event handler that clears and reset the timer whenever the user begins typing.